# Unable to use graphical interface after logging back into Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gui, ubuntu-gnome

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04. Every other time I log in (after having closed the lip on my laptop, letting it sleep), I am unable to use most of the graphical interface. I say "most", because right clicks still register and bring up the menu, although clicking on any of the selections doesn't register. The keys do work (<kbd>F12</kbd> does give me the Guake terminal which I can use, and <kbd>F1</kbd> gives me "Help"), but, again, I am unable to click on anything and have to restart. After that, everything works fine (until it happens again).

Answer (score 0):

I cannot tell you why that's happening but I can suggest some things that can help you find out.  You can open a console and look at log files by pressing Ctrl-Alt-F2 then logging in.  Look at the system log with this command:

less /var/log/syslog

You can skip to the bottom of the file (to view the most recent entries) by pressing shift-g.

You can also look at the Xorg log which might contain useful information:

less /var/log/Xorg.0.log

And query the systemd journal:

sudo journalctl -xe

Instead of rebooting you can also restart the display manager which will end the current graphical session and enable you to log in again:

sudo systemctl restart gdm

This is assuming you're using Gnome.  If you're suing KDE change gdm to sddm.